# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a comment model for a post in django.I want to print the user name along with the comment.

This is my comment model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey('app.Item', related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

This is my view

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = user.username
            comment.item = item
            comment.save()
            return redirect('item_detail', pk=item.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'app/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form}
```

)

This is my html code

```
{% for comment in item.comments.all %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="date">
            {{ comment.created_date }}
            {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <p> {{comment.user}} <p>
        <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Error during template rendering

In template /home/deepu/django/e-commerce/app/templates/app/item_detail.html, error at line 34   <p> {{comment.user}} <p>

Comment: Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /home/deepu/django/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _resolve_lookup

                            current = current[bit]

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    During handling of the above exception ('Comment' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:
    /home/deepu/django/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __get__

                    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars

Comment: During handling of the above exception ('Comment' object has no attribute '_user_cache'), another exception occurred:
    /home/deepu/django/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner

                    response = get_response(request)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars

Comment: Don't post this as comments, edit your post, and put it there.

Comment: And see that bit you quoted that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view"? **Click it**, and paste the results.